# Performing operation when either android activity is open or not

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

I want to update my list view whether that particular activity is open or not by calling the function of that activity on random intervals, or on the other hand tell me if its possible that if you can sense that activity is open or not? so that I only call the function of that particular activity only when the activity is open or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting API level 14 or above you can use [Application#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29) if target is lower then you can override lifecycle callbacks (eg. `onPause`) in each activity and collect information about calls. It depends what do you mean by "open", you can assume eg. that `Activity` is open between `onResume` and `onPause` calls.